# classic asp image upload with flex

Tags: apache-flex, image, asp-classic, upload

Is there a way to upload an image using flex inbuild .browse() and classic asp?

So in flex the user picks the image they want to upload, press a button to start sending it. A asp handler then gets the file, uploads it to a folder and then writes the filename in a database.

Writing of the filename in the database is no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is but you have to have an ASP component such as ASPUpload on the server to allow it.

Comment: I found out this is impossible (even with the ASPUpload component).

The ASPUpload component needs the path of a file on a computer. Flex however cannot get the path to the location of the file. AIR can do this, so image upload with AIR is possible.